# Capture data output from stored procedure in postgres (pgadmin)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I am trying to capture the data output from a stored procedure in pgAdmin, when I execute the function outside of stored procedure, I get the following in data output section:

```
"1942 rows imported into relation ""public.tblname"" from file XXX of 26 bytes"
```

Function used is shown here:

```
select(
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3
('public.tblname'
, ''
, '(FORMAT CSV,DELIMITER ''|''
, QUOTE ''"'',  NULL '''')'
, 's3bucket', 'path/XXX', 'region'));
```

If I use this function in a stored procedure, how can I capture data output into a variable?

Comment: This question needs improving: 1) Do not use screenshots. Copy and past output as text as update to your question. 2) Include text of function as update to your function. 3) Indicate what information you want returned.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/rowtypes.html
Also, what's the reason for the double **SELECT**?

Comment: @DonR Chose to enter double select to see if I can capture the data output of internal select in another variable using the outer select which didn't worked.